# Survival of manually edited variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have some environmental variables set in my .profile, and thus the variables can be set automatically when I log in. In some special cases, I also need to change some settings using the command "export", just like:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=3
```

When I manually edit an environmental variable, run a software which requires the variable with nohup, and then log out. Does the variable turn back at the moment I exit?

Comment: Did you test this? It's not difficult to test.

Comment: How to test the settings after I exit my server?

Comment: You login again and see if the variables have the value you set? O.o

Comment: It turns back to the value that I set in my .profile, but I don't know what the value is when I am not on server...

Answer (score 0):

For the program that you started with `nohup`, no, the variable won't be reset because you logged out (unless it's a program that watches for you logging out and then resets the variable, or some such weirdness).

Each process has its own copy of environment variables. For a process X, other processes cannot typically change X's copy of variables without X's cooperation. This is also why a script cannot change the current shell's variables [unless it is sourced](https://askubuntu.com/q/53177/158442).

So, once you start the process, it gets a copy of `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. What you then do in your shell (including setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to another value, logging out, starting another shell, sacrificing to Cthulhu) won't affect X's environment variables.