Are there limitation to how i can effect a terminal window title
New to bash scripting and looking to tidy my screen.  I have a number of terminal windows running separate process but all with the same window title.  Using the following i can change the title.. all well and good:
PS1='\[\e]0;TEST TITLE HERE: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'

If i place this inside a script, it has no effect:
#! /bin/bash
PS1='\[\e]0;TEST TITLE HERE: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'

What element of scripting have i failed to appreciate that prevents me from doing what I'm trying to do?
many thanks

https://askubuntu.com/q/53177/380067 - In short, you can't affect the parent shell's environment from a subshell; you can fix this by running your script as . script.sh or source script.sh instead of ./script.sh

Although the man page was never changed, gnome-terminal has not allowed the -t title business for awhile. xlogo still allows that however if you want to see how things used to work under X.

@ubfan1 What's the problem with gnome-terminal's -t option or the manual? The man page says "Set the initial terminal title" and that's exactly what the option does: sets the initial title. Works exactly as documented.

Nope. gnome-terminal -t Fails will pop up a new terminal with the usual title of user@machine:directory The requested title of "Fails" is not displayed. Probably some change to the gnome-terminal python script changed things, and the docs never caught up. @egmont Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04 behavior -- what system are you running?  (the man page of -t=TITLE with the = sign is simply a syntax error)

The shell, immediately after starting up, changes the title. The initial one is so short-lived that you probably don't see it. But it's not gnome-terminal's fault, it cannot know that it will be changed so soon. Change your shell prompt not to update the title, or launch a custom command, you will see the initial title working.

Now the OP has a lot of things going on in his PS1, below I have removed the major portion of it, to create as simple text as possible - with a solution to the actual problem.
Using a bash FUNCTION you can get the same effect
as from using a script (source script.sh).
$ man bash, then type in /^FUNCTIONS, for info on bash functions.
Example,
place this in .bash_aliases

function setps1 {
PS1="\[\e]0;$1 \a\]$ "
}

Then every bash has the setps1 function available... so
$ type -a setps1 will print

setps1 is a function
setps1 () 
{ 
    PS1="\[\e]0;$1 \a\]$ "
}

and
$ setps1 "Working in \\w"
... will indeed set the window title to "Working in <cwd>"
i.e. Working in Projects while you're cd'd into ...anything/Projects/,
following along as you move about.

You probably want to extend that to something like  function setps1 { PS1="\[\e]0;$1 \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "; } to also preserve the original prompt while setting the title ... I think.

I intentionally left out that portion of OP's prompt to make it clear how the title-setting works.

(i.e. leave out all but the essentials)

Ok, but some people might just copy/paste the function and then decide it doesn't work as their original prompt will be empty.

Now it should be clearer regarding that...

Note that \\w will make the prompt "dynamic" w.r.t. cwd, i.e. no need to setps1 more than once for having cwd visible. Test: Well, apparently even \w will make ps1 dynamic

Huh sorry I didn't read that portion of the answer, the way you did it is way better.

@Raffa this is exactly why i had all the noise on my original post; i'd already fallen into that trap :D
